# Is it a finished basement or a furnished basement?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, differences

When one buys a house with a fully done basement, is it known as a furnished basement or a finished basement? I’ve heard both used, but I was always under the impression that the right usage is a furnished basement. I thought, being that the words sound similar, the two terms became confused and eventually interchangeable, but perhaps both are correct. Regardless, any logical, coherent answer to this question would be appreciated!

Comment: Furnished means it has furniture as opposed to unfurnished meaning it has no furniture. Finished means it is plumbed (has plumbing), has electrical, is painted, etc. You could have bare stud walls with furniture and technically be furnished but not finished. You could have a finished basement with no furniture, so it would be considered not "finished" (aka unfinished).

Comment: @JeffC Electrical I could agree with, but I don't think that all finished basements are plumbed.

Comment: @KennethK. Well finished means finished walls so if you plan to have plumbing, you better have it in before the walls are done. I guess it's possible to not have *any* plumbing at all in a basement, I've just never seen it that I remember. Usually a basement has a laundry room, a water heater, a bathroom, or a sink ... some reason to have plumbing.

Comment: @JeffC Please don't post answers as comments.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Both expressions are used, they just refer to  different contexts:

***[Finished basement:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/finished%20basement/attic)***

> a basement that has floors, ceilings, and walls like the rooms in the main part of the house. (M-W)

[image: Photo of a basement with a carpeted floor, painted walls, and a drop ceiling with recessed lighting.]

***[Furnished basement:](https://www.google.it/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&ei=xAlrW-TnHoKUlwSb2ZrwDQ&q=furnished%20basement&oq=furnished%20basement&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.3...0.0..2609...0.0..1.0.0.......4.UDEx-66z3h8&pccc=1)***

> A basement equipped with furniture so that you can comfortably live in it.

[image: Photo of a basement with a TV, couch, chair, dresser, rugs, and artwork.]

From [fullhomeliving.com](https://www.fullhomeliving.com/walkout-basement-ideas/)

Please compare with a ***partially finished basement:***

[image: Photo of basement with a linoleum floor and painted walls but with exposed support posts and an exposed ceiling.]

From Tim Wohforth Blog

Comment: Will a furnished basement automatically be finished as well?

Comment: It would be unusual, but not impossible, to furnish an unfinished basement.  I would ask whether a basement was finished before paying for a furnished basement, but I wouldn't be surprised if the seller were insulted by the question.

Comment: @TheWordsmith - it appears the main issue is finished vs partially finished basement when buying a house: https://www.google.it/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&hl=it&ei=4QxrW7ewGKiNlwT78pXYAg&q=finished+or+partially+finised++basement&oq=finished+or+partially+finised++basement&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.3..0i13i30.15131.21913..22157...0.0..0.307.3662.0j15j5j1......0....1.........0i7i30i19j0i7i10i30i19j0i7i30j0i8i30j0i8i7i30j0i8i7i10i30j33i10.TXt1fhBNIZ0

Comment: @TheWordsmith - but you are right, there are pictures where “finished” is actually used to mean also “furnished”. https://www.google.it/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&hl=it&ei=-gxrW9zAGcyca-GOk6AN&q=finished+basement+&oq=finished+basement+&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.3..0i19l5.122096.127934..128272...0.0..0.314.3281.0j13j4j1......0....1.......3..0j41j46j0i67j0i131j0i67i70i255j46i131j0i10i19j0i13i30i19j0i22i30i19.izRn0pLQAQw#imgdii=HMNUPjcjYKQeeM:&imgrc=_5-cyJ6xCDz02M:

Comment: @user070221 This is where my confusion arose from.

Comment: You could add a picture of an unfinished basement.

Comment: That is a surprisingly finished unfinished basement, I was thinking unpainted bare concrete walls.

Comment: @Ash - And the Finished Basement is unfortunately well furnished. And the Furnished Basement is unfortunately at ground level.

Comment: @NigelTouch It is too, I didn't really look at that one, actually the unfinished basement is in fact worryingly well furnished too, I would think it would be too healthy to stay there for too long.

Comment: @user070221 Your second picture is of a finished basement, no? It has walls and a ceiling, and the floor is simply polished concrete. (I think.)

Comment: I don't think any of those pictures is a good example. The picture for the finished basement fits better for a furnished basement. The picture for the furnished basement does not even look like a basement, because it has a ground level exit. The picture for the partially finished basement is also partially furnished and does not show very much of the room. We appreciate the effort, but there must be better pictures out there.

Comment: @NigelTouch: There are houses with different ground levels on either side of the house. It's not impossible for a basement to not be subterranean on all sides. Ignoring the window, the pillars and concrete floor strongly suggest that this is indeed a basement.

Comment: As others have pointed out, the pictures are too ambiguous. The core of your answer is good, but I would suggest focusing more on semantical definition. Furnished = has furniture, finished = construction work on the walls/floor/ceiling has been completed.

Comment: @Ian I think the first picture is a good example of a finished basement. The second picture is also of a finished basement, so that may not be the best contrasting example between furnished and finished. But the third picture *does* show a partially finished basement. I see no reason why people do not find the pictures satisfactory.

Comment: @TheWordsmith If you do not see the reason why people get so worked up over these pictures (which, based on the number of comments, they do), then I am very sorry to say that you might not have the best judgement to provide satisfactory pictures to this otherwise very concise answer (no offense). The first picture has actual *furniture* in it. It is, by definition, furnished. Just because Google Image Search does not have a proper distinction does not mean we should not be very pedantic about this pressing matter ;'D

Comment: @Ian Well, I suppose it’s a matter of perspective; the pictures are, after all, meant to help answer *my* question.

Comment: @Ian Based on Merriam-Webster’s definition, the first picture *does* show a finished (albeit also furnished) basement.

Answer (score 10):

A finished basement is one that has proper stud walls and plaster ceilings, possibly also plumbing etc...

A furnished basement should be just that furnished; having a full suite of furniture that defines the space as a functional lounge, workshop, bedroom or what have you.

Comment: It's rare to buy a house furnished, but the basement being finished adds a lot of value. But suppose you were renting a whole house, furnished, for a short-term stay. The basement might be "finished", but empty, probably of little use to you; or furnished, as a whole 'nother level of the house to use.

Comment: @CCTO I'll have to take your word for the value of a basement, we don't, as a rule, have them in houses only large commercial buildings and then mainly only for parking.

Answer (score 1):

I have often regarded this word as an [eggcorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn), as I have heard it used in both contexts to refer to the same thing. In the Southern United States this seems to be particularly true, as there are fewer basements and thus not as much care is given to terminology with respect to this topic.

Comment: OK...but which one came first?

Answer (score 0):

Given that a basement is the lowest habitable part of a building (wholly or *partly* underground, were it not finished, it wouldn't be habitable, I'd have thought. But an ordinary room in a house above ground level may well be finished, but waiting for furniture, which, when it is installed, makes the room furnished. Without furniture, a room, anywhere, is said to be unfurnished. Therefore, a basement, or any room, can be finished, but unfurnished. If it was furnished, it pretty well has to be assumed that it was a finished room before putting furniture in it.

It is quite possible that an estate agent may massage things, and advertise a finished basement as a furnished basement, or vice versa, to encourage 'good' marketing...